# I have been using the ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup(); for selenium testing

Tags: selenium

My code runs but I don't see the browser while running the test case.
I have updated this dependency in my pom.xml

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

my code

```
ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
     ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
     options.addArguments("--headless");
     options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
     WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
     driver.get("http://www.google.com");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println("the browser is loaded");
         if( driver.findElement(By.name("q")).isDisplayed()){
                System.out.println("Element is Visible");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Element is InVisible");
            }
```

Comment: So what is the issue exactly? Do you get an exception? Or you want to actually see the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no exception but you are looking for the browser to visible. Then you should be using a non-headless browser. You can change

```
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.addArguments("--headless");
 options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

to

```
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

And now your browser will be visible. If you get an exception instead, please update the question

Comment: Great! If the answer helped you should accept and upvote the answer

Answer (score 0):

remove 
    options.addArguments("--headless");
and its preferable to use the following options:

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--disable-plugins");
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.addArguments("window-size=1280x1024");
```